# Synchronous RxJs unsubscription not working

Tags: rxjs, observable, subscription, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-unsubscribe-issue?file=index.ts

**Below code is not working**

> Error: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

```js
    const a = (): Observable<any> =>
    new Observable(sub => {
      sub.next(1);
      return () => {
        console.log('unsubscribe');
      };
    });
    const observer = a().subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log('Subscription');
        observer.unsubscribe();
      },
      e => console.log(e),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
```

**But the following code is working**

```js
    const b = (): Observable<any> =>
    new Observable(sub => {
      setTimeout(()=>sub.next(1),0);
      return () => {
        console.log('unsubscribe');
      };
    });
    const observer2 = b().subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log('Subscription b');
        observer2.unsubscribe();
      },
      e => console.log(e),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
```

*Help me understand the reason behind it*

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned in the title of your question, the first example is synchronous, so you get the first value while still inside of the `.subscribe()` method. Naturally, `observer`, which is supposed to have a `Subscription` object hasn't been initialized yet.

If you want to unsubscribe after receiving a single value I would suggest to use `.take(1)`